# API for Big5 personality assessments?

Tags: big-five

To be clear, I don't want a tool for integrating a Big-5 test into my own app, but rather an API where I can ping with data (structured, semi-structured or unstructured) data and get back a score on personality (similar to applymagicsauce.com)

Here's a few that I've found: [This](https://docs.receptiviti.com/the-receptiviti-api), [this](https://api.humantic.ai/), and [this](https://www.symanto.com/nlp-tools/nlp-api/big-five-personality-traits-api/).

Any more in particular that you can recommend? Thank you!